# Gradle build fails on "Configure Build"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have seen all the related answers and I'm still not able to fix the errors. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: The actual error would be nice..

Comment: Please paste your logcat here instead of a screenshot...

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'TimeFighter'.

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50)

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0):

These are certain points that may help you:

1. You have forgotten to add semicolons
2. Make sure you are connected to the internet as project sync and gradle build may require some additional automatic downloads.
3. Please provide logcat instead of screenshot to identify the correct error

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'TimeFighter'

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50)

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

Comment: yeah i have connected to the internet